# If I set an alarm clock with a ringtone, how long will the ringtone run if I do not stop it?

Tags: iphone

If I set the iphone alarm clock with a ringtone, how long will the ringtone run if I do not stop it?

Will it run all the way until it runs out of battery and the phone shuts down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this with iPhone 3GS iOS 5.1 and the alarm stopped after exactly 15 minutes.

Comment: Any chance someone can test, confirm, and update the answer with the latest version of iOS?

Comment: testing... this could get annoying ;-)

Comment: Alarm stopped at 15 mins, on iPhone 6S, iOS 9.3.1 - however, the screen has dimmed but will not sleep with the alert still showing

Comment: hmm... it's actually 16 minutes. Tested again, as I wasn't certain to the absolute minute first time. Also, if the screen was off to start with, it stays off.

Answer (score 4):

Indefinitely, near as I can tell. I once had my phone go for over a half hour on an alarm.

Comment: a half hour and indefinitely is **totally different**.

Comment: Since the ringtone almost certainly isn't 20+ minutes, it's obviously looping the tone. No setting users can control last longer than 5 minutes, so I'd call 30m ~ indefinitely. It would be theoretically interesting to see if either of the low voltage alerts pause the audio, but I'll leave that for another day ;-)

Comment: @bmike is right. Since the phone is looping the same sound, 30 minutes might as well be indefinitely. There is a reason why I qualified my answer with "near as I can tell."